# python/pandas properly implementing df.loc with a variable

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a variable called

```
Date: "2016-07-01"
```

and I am trying to make it so the dataframe I currently have starts at the given date. The method I am currently using is:

```
given base df with many dates and prices at the time,

dfmain = df.loc[Date:]
```

However when I print the output it actually just starts at Index 202:

```
Index    Date      Price  
202  2008-11-21    37.88
203  2008-11-28    42.70 
204  2008-12-05    48.28 
205  2008-12-12    51.34 
206  2008-12-19    51.30 
207  2008-12-26    51.78  #etc...
```

when I changed Date to something like 2076-01-02, it starts from index 208. I was wondering if there was a way to implement it so it takes the full date and start from there, instead of df.loc calculating the first three numbers of the date and setting that as the starter index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need first `set_index` to `DateTimeindex` by column `Date` for select by labels by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.index)
Int64Index([202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207], dtype='int64', name='Index')
```

---

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2008-11-21', '2008-11-28', '2008-12-05', '2008-12-12',
               '2008-12-19', '2008-12-26'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)

Date =  "2008-12-01"

dfmain = df.loc[Date:]
print (dfmain)
            Price
Date             
2008-12-05  48.28
2008-12-12  51.34
2008-12-19  51.30
2008-12-26  51.78
```

Another solution should be use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
Date =  "2008-12-01"

dfmain = df[df['Date'] >= Date]
```

---

```
#dfmain = df.query('Date >= @Date')
print (dfmain)
            Date  Price
Index                  
204   2008-12-05  48.28
205   2008-12-12  51.34
206   2008-12-19  51.30
207   2008-12-26  51.78
```

Answer (score 3):

df.loc[] is a reference to your index, and your index is not your date column.  Try:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

If you don't want to change your index, you could also do:

```
df[df['Date'] >= '20160701']]
```